# Subsetting Puts from getOptionChain in Quantmod

Tags: r, subset, quantmod

The result of running the getOptionChain is a list of symbols that includes both Calls and Puts.

I would like to subset the data and create a **dataset that will include only the Puts**.

This is the code I'm running to get the option chain. Now I need to subset and create a new dataset only for Puts.

```
library(quantmod)
Symbols<-c  ("AA","AAL","AAOI","ABBV","ABC","ABNB")
Options.20221111 <- lapply(Symbols, getOptionChain)
names(Options.20221111) <- Symbols
```

What is the best approach to get the Puts alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with lists, `lapply` is your friend.

```
only_puts_list <- lapply(Options.20221111, function(x) x$puts)
```

This will create a list with only the puts in there.